# Doubt at the middle of a calculus problem - involving trigonometry

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

(These steps are from the middle of a problem which is aimed at finding the n-th derivative)

...

$ y' = be^{ax} \cos(bx+c) + a e^{ax} \sin(bx+c) $

Putting $ a = r \cos(H) , b = r \sin(H) $

$ y' = r e^{ax} sin(bx+c+H) $ (Doubt at this step)

...

Please tell me how and why we assume a value for a & b where they remain as constants still. And, if we assume it, how do we arrive the last step from it?

The full problem is here :

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But how the conversion happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a$ and $b$ are just constants. The problem writes them as $r\sin \phi$ and $r\cos\phi$ just for convenience, s.t. later they can be converted into one sine function. (You can see that if $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $\phi=\arctan(b/a)$, you can derive $r\sin\phi=a$ and $r\cos\phi=b$)

The conversion is actually pretty easy. $$y'=re^{ax}\left(\sin\phi\cos(bx+c)+\cos\phi\sin(bx+c)\right)$$
Since $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\cos a\sin b$, you can get the derivative.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the conversion to sine function ?

Comment: @DeepakS.M I have shown the conversion in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and care :)